# proguard Note: duplicate definition of program class com.facebook.android.R.string how do I fix this?

Tags: android, proguard

How do I resolve this note from proguard. What are the implications of a duplicate definition? Do I need to fix this and if so how? I'm also seeing:

```
[proguard] Note: there were 625 duplicate class definitions.
[proguard] Initializing...
[proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class      'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
```

I'm also seeing:

```
  [proguard] Reading program jar [/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar]
  [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of program class [com.google.ads.Ad] etc.
```

taking out

```
   injars  bin/classes
```

helped reduce this down to 200 classes.  But for each library jar I am including I am seeing the above. Same for Google analytics jar file.

And I am seeing:

```
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of program class [com.test.activities.MyActivity]
```

Where MyActivity only appears in one of my projects ...  how do I get rid of this?

Comment: Guys if it is a basic question please just give a quick answer!

Comment: I am getting this for almost all classes that are in my project. I am pretty sure I only defined once every class - NetBeans would not compile the project otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Proguard Duplicate Definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805704/android-proguard-duplicate-definition)

Answer (score -1):

The [Proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html) states the following:

> **Note: duplicate definition of program/library class**
>
> Your program jars or library jars contain multiple definitions of the listed classes. ProGuard continues processing as usual, only considering the first definitions. The warning may be an indication of some problem though, so it's advisable to remove the duplicates. A convenient way to do so is by specifying filters on the input jars or library jars. You can switch off these notes by specifying the -dontnote option.

In my experience it's not so much that you have multiple class definitions, but that you need to configure proguard better. In any case it's not a big problem and things will probably work fine as it is.

Comment: Ok, so you're telling me he's got 625 duplicate class definitions in his project? How come IDE doesn't highlight it as conflict?

Comment: @TomášZato Nope, I was implicitely saying that it's probably not a big problem and if it is, it's a matter of configuring proguard better.