# ProGuard with Android app -> duplicate definition

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I am trying to enable ProGuard when compiling my Android application.

Below is the ProGuard configuration.

The problem I have is that I get a lot of warnings about duplicate definition (pretty much for all classes, in my app or the basic java classes) and what's worse is that when I make changes in my code, those do not get reflected when I run on the device.

I am compiling (and developing) using IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5 (and just enable ProGuard in the project structure, I did not set it to use the system proguard configuration).

I saw [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805704/android-proguard-duplicate-definition), but it does not help at all, I don't think my problem is limited to 3rd party libraries, I imagine it's more about setting the right input/output... ?

```
-injars      bin/classes
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /home/matthieu/android/platforms/android-17/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**,com.sun.**

-keep public class my.package.MainMenuActivity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keep public class * extends android.app.Service

-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver

-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.ViewGroup
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

#ACRA specifics

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are building with Ant inside IntelliJ IDEA, you mustn't add -injars, -outjars, or -libraryjars options; the Ant script already does that for you. This explains the warnings about duplicates.

Note that it's better to remove the generic part of the configuration in your proguard-project.txt and rely on the configuration of the Android SDK. The latter is partly generated by aapt (tuned for your project) and partly maintained inside the SDK.

Comment: Yes, removing those options at the beginning fixed it.